# UINavigationBar visual error during push with UIToolbar

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

When using a UIToolbar, there is a visual error during the push animation on the UINavigationBar.

[image: Visual Error]

It appears that during the push animation, the view being pushed onto the screen does not appear under the navigation bar. Instead, the dark background of the app can be seen as the previous view slides to the left. Once the pushed view takes over the screen, it's background contents flash into view under the navigation bar.

I have determined that it is definitely the UIToolbar causing this issue, as marking it as hidden in the Storyboard resolves the visual error.

This is running iOS 8.4.

Does anyone know of any workarounds / has it been submitted as a bug to Apple yet?